# Timezone in Watson Dialog for Android

Tags: android, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

My Watson Dialog is configured so that for a certain intent it answers me with something depending on whether it's Sunday. When I try it with the "try it" panel it gives me the correct answer at all times.
However, when I try it with the Android SDK at saturday night in my timezone (Americas/Bogota), it answers me like if it was Sunday.
How can I set the timezone in Android so that it knows that is still saturday?

Comment: Can you please add some code for what have you tried and where exactly you are getting the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The try out panel grabs your browser locale and uses that. By default, the system will use UCT I believe unless you set the time zone in context:
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/supported-timezones.html